# Nciku Chinese and Japanese

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I am one of the Chinese moderators, and I came here to ask for information about Nciku and our SE sites. Nciku is very famous both on CL&U and JL&U, but I noticed a difference between the [Japanese](http://japanese.nciku.com/) and [Chinese](http://www.nciku.com/) version of the site.

The Japanese Nciku displays links, depending on what you search, that link to JL&U related questions. The Chinese one hasn't and I think it'd be great if we could have our site linked there in a dynamic way, like yours.

So I was wondering if you did this yourselves (as in asking Nciku to link your site) or if they did by themselves, or... I don't know. :) This is why I decided to ask here.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd guess they did it by themselves using the Stack Exchange API or something, I think you might have to ask them. Nciku used to have a competing Q&A service for Chinese, but they've since shut it down. BTW I'm not sure whether they're still planning to shut down the Japanese Nciku but it was on the agenda at their [blog post](http://blog.nciku.com/blog/en/2012/07/26/discontinuing-some-less-popular-nciku-services/) (which is a pity, because it's a pretty useful tool IMHO).

Comment: @cypher Whoa! I didn't know about that... Yes, it's certainly a pity! :S I hope they revise their decision.

Comment: No-one can help us? :P